# OleDbCommandBuilder Update - at least one parameter values are missing

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

**What I did:**
I am using OleDbAdapter to read from the database, getting a fresh DataTable filled. This went good. Then I want to add a column into that DataTable, which also went good.

I added a OleDbCommandBuilder, to update the database with the DataTable having one more column. And I tried it with the 'automatical way' of the OleDbCommandBuilder, as I thought what I want is simple. But so far this did not work.

**What I expect**
is that the OleDbCommandBuilder is writing a fresh SQL command for me, having 'UPDATE' or 'INSERT' contained. I further expect, that I can't read all Commands within the OleDbAdapter, except the SELECT command, because OleDbAdapter takes the commands from the builder right before using them.

I have read in the internet, that adapter.Fill(...) is not necessary if I let call adapter.Update(...). But without adapter.Fill(...) I don't get content from the database.

**Finally a problem has got a name:**

Now, after searching for the problem, I got the following message: System.Data.OleDbException: For at least one parameter no value has been given.

**My questions:**

1) Do I expect something wrong?

2) Which parameter hasn't got a value? **Solved** This helped me to understand:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters

3) Are the adapter, builder ... placed in the right order?

4) Have I got something additional to do, like calling a function to update the SQL command withing the adapter?

5) How can I improve the way I solve that problem? E.g.: Is there any event which will help me to understand more what is going on? How to catch such an event?

Many thanks in advance!

This is the my code - originally it is divided into two functions. But I put it all in one for you:

```
  public virtual bool AddColumnOfString_ToDataTable(string tableName, string newColumnName, string defaultCellValue)
    {
       /// Approach: Accessing database at minimum time.
       ///    returns true if  column name could not be found and column could be added

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string strSQL = "SELECT " + tableName;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnection);
        adapter.Fill(table);     
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

        bool result = false;

        if (false == HasColumn(newColumnName))
        {
            DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn(newColumnName, typeof(System.String));
            newColumn.DefaultValue = defaultCellValue;
            table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
            result = true;
        }

        adapter.Update(table);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I was never a fan of command builders. Take the guesswork out and just add your own select, insert, update and delete commands.

Comment: Well, at first sight, querying a datatable on a column that could not exist  and then adding the missing column to the returned datatable doesn't seems very logic

Comment: Steve you are right. I corrected it but I still got the same error message. _adapter.Fill(table)_ seems to cause the problem.

Comment: Adding to a DataTable is not the same as adding a column to a DB Table. Why do you need to add columns at runtime?

Comment: @Plutonix: Because from time to time DB changes. The programm changes old DB to get them align with new ones. Its a stand alone programm used by many users, catching content from a MS Access DB.

Comment: If you are hoping that the DataAdapter will alter the DB for you because you added a column to a DataTable, thats not how it works.  You need DDL for that

Comment: `string strSQL = "SELECT " + tableName;` What is this supposed to build? Have you looked at the generated SQL?

Comment: I updated my answer and add a method to modify table structure in MS access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modified the structure of the DataTable  by adding newcolumn to the datatable and this is not reflected in the generated update/insert/delete sql commands.

Have a look to this example: [OleDbCommandBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

so simply:

```
   adapter.Update(table);
```

Only update the data in the base table in the server (if changed)

> 1) Do I expect something wrong?

No, it's working but no change in the structure of base table in MS access

> 2) Which parameter hasn't got a value?

you don't pass parameters in the SQL command

> 3) Are the adapter, builder ... placed in the right order?

yes, but remove the part that modify the datatable. It has no effect

> 4) Have I got something additional to do, like calling a function to update the SQL command withing the adapter?

rview my code with the comments.

> 5) How can I improve the way I solve that problem? E.g.: Is there any event which will help me to understand more what is going on? How to catch such an event?

You can't modify the structure of the datatable by adding new columns

**Update**

I test your code , modified it with comments:

```
       public  bool AddColumnOfString_ToDataTable(string tableName, string newColumnName, string defaultCellValue)
            {
                // Approach: Accessing database at minimum time.
                //    returns true if  column name could not be found and column could be added

                DataTable table = new DataTable();


                //string strSQL = "SELECT " + tableName; // not valid syntax
                string strSQL = "SELECT * from " + tableName;
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnectionString);
                adapter.Fill(table);
                OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

                bool result = false;
                // remove this code, it has no effect on the underlying base table in MS Access databas
                //any change in the structure of datatable has no effect on the database

                /*
                if (false == table.HasColumn(newColumnName))
                {
                    DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn(newColumnName, typeof(System.String));
                    newColumn.DefaultValue = defaultCellValue;
                    table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
                    result = true;
                }
                */

                //  code to modify data in DataTable here

                //Without the OleDbCommandBuilder this line would fail
                adapter.Update(table);

                //just to review the generated code                 
                Console.WriteLine(builder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText);
                Console.WriteLine(builder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText);
                return result;
            }
```

**Update2:**

If you are interested for adding new column to MS Access Database, you can run the following code:

```
 public   bool AddColumn(OleDbConnection con, 
                string tableName,string colName,string colType, object defaultValue)
            {
                string query = $"ALTER TABLE {tableName}  ADD COLUMN {colName} {colType} DEFAULT {defaultValue} ";
                var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Sql Executed Successfully");
                    return true;
                }
                catch (OleDbException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Details: " + e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("closing conn");
                    con.Close();
                }
                return false;
            }

      public   void AddColumnTest()
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
                string tableName="table1";
                string colName="country";
                string colType="text (30)";
                object defaultValue = "USA";
                AddColumn(con, tableName, colName, colType, defaultValue);
            }
```

I test the code with MS Access and it's working fine.

Comment: 1) I understand now that Update means just synchronizing values, it is not supposed to change the structure of the database, like adding columns. Is this right?

Comment: 2) My idea was that I get content and structure of the database by reading. Then I modify the DataTable I got "from" the database. And by giving a changed DataTable back via Update, the structure of the database will also change. This strategy won't work, right?

Comment: 3) Can I update a complete table by content of a DataTable? (only values, leaving the structure of the table unchanged.)